# Unable to scroll iframe inside of fb instant article

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, iframe, facebook-instant-articles

On iPhone using the facebook app. The article in question has a spotify playlist and a soundcloud playlist on it and I am unable to scroll either playlist.

Adding `class="op-interactive"` or `class="op-social"` seems to have no affect on the usability of the iframe.

I'm assuming that this an issue with facebook handling the control with the user touch event.

I'm open to clever fixes or loud yelling and the waving of fists at facebook.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer for this question? I'm asking the same. I think that Facebook IA does not allow iframes with internal scroll.